# Script doesn't show sqlcode

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, shell, sqlplus

I have a lot of shell scripts to execute procedures and other tasks on an Oracle database. In general, they have the same structure, check for envvars, execute sql and use `show sqlcode` to know if the script was executed successfully or not.

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Check for var's in another script
. /home/oracle/cron/scripts/exp_variaveis.sh

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus User/pass@database <<!
spool /home/oracle/cron/log/some_name.log_$date_log

set serveroutput on
DECLARE
   V_QTD NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(*) QTD
INTO V_QTD
FROM D.TB_R_A TRA
   WHERE TRA.CD_STATUS = 'A'
     AND TRA.CD_T_AUT = 'E'
     AND TRA.DT_P < TRUNC(SYSDATE);

  IF V_QTD = 0 THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Sem resgates para serem expirados.');
  ELSE

  FOR R1 IN (SELECT TRA.CD_R, TRA.CD_A, TRA.CD_O
             from D.TB_R_A TRA
                WHERE TRA.CD_STATUS = 'A'
                  AND TRA.CD_T_AUT = 'E'
                  and TRA.DT_P < TRUNC(sysdate))
    LOOP   

  BEGIN

    UPDATE D.TB_R_A T
       SET T.CD_STATUS = 'E'
         WHERE T.CD_R = R1.CD_R;

    COMMIT;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Resgate expirado: ' || R1.CD_R);

     EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
           ROLLBACK;
           DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Falha na expiracao do resgate: ' || R1.CD_R);
      END;

    END LOOP;

  END IF; 

END;
-- command show slqcode to know if was executed with success
show sqlcode

spool off
exit
!
# A variavel recebe a instrucao de busca do arquivo e se existir reporta o "sqlcode 0" que equilave a "SUCESSO"
sql_code=`grep -i "sqlcode 0" /home/oracle/cron/log/some_name.log_$date_log`

# A variavel trata a instrucao acima e processa os dados nos textos e   operacoess com arquivos (awk) mostrando de forma CSV (-F)
# apresentando as strings da segunda coluna '{ print $2 }'
ret_code=`echo $sql_code | awk -F" " '{ print $2 }'`

# Se a variavel $ret_code for diferente de 0
if [ "$ret_code" != 0 ]

then
# Send error message
mail dbajob@domain.com -s "!! ERROR !! CRON => DATABASE - SOME TEXT HERE" < /home/oracle/cron/log/some_name.log_$date_log
exit 1
else
# Send sucessful message
mail dbajob@domain.com -s "Job OK CRON => DATABASE - SOME TEXTE HERE" < /home/oracle/cron/log/some_name.log_$date_log
exit 0
fi
```

My problem is: This sql doesn't output the sqlcode, so if my script doesn't find the string "sqlcode" on log, it sends an error message even if it was executed successfully.

Please somebody tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that SQLCODE will always return 0 when used outside of an exception handler, as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqlcode_function.htm):

> `SQLCODE` is only useful in an exception handler. Outside a handler, `SQLCODE` always returns 0.

But the reason you do not even see that 0 output, is that you never execute the PL/SQL code block and so the `show` statement is not recognised as a statement to execute immediately. You need to add a line with a [forward slash (/)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_twelve004.htm#SQPUG162):

> **/(slash)**
>
> Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which is stored in the SQL buffer.

So place that slash here:

```sql
    END LOOP;
  END IF; 
END;
/
-- command show slqcode will always show 0.
show sqlcode
```

Comment: Something like this:" END LOOP;  END IF; END; \ show sqlcode spool off exit" ?

Comment: It should be a forward slash, not a backslash. Added to my answer.